# How to create a CustomControl from Sealed controls in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How to create a CustomControl from Sealed controls in Silverlight.
one of the thing i want to create a custom control from ScrollViewer in silverlight,
but as this is a sealed class i am not able to create a custom control, 
to overcome this i have creted a usercontrol and defined my own Content property to set content of scrollViewer, but then i am not able to find the controls inside scrollviewer.
Any suggestions.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish with your custom control? You may be better off using a control template, rather than class inheritance.

Comment: @joe: i want to incorporate the scrollBar style in scrollViewer, so that there is no need to implement style every where, just we use that control from centralized control library, and changes in scrollViewer is done in one place so that they will be reflected every where. I think you got my point. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just put a `<Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">` in your Application.Resources, then? That will automatically set whatever properties you want on all the ScrollViewers in your application.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks Joe, it works. Just what i want. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Very Simple solution yet effective suggested by JOE White.
I have just copied the style for a ScrollViewer in Application.Resources file.
And i am done.
Thank Joe.